# Trigger after insert with condition in oracle

Tags: if-statement, oracle11g, triggers

I have an error with my trigger. it show

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------
2/2      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2/6      PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

I want this trigger run if the customertype is member.

Here are my table
TABLE CUSTOMER

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(CUSTOMERID VARCHAR2(100) primary key,
CUSTOMERNAME VARCHAR2(50), 
CUSTOMERADDRESS VARCHAR2(100), 
CUSTOMERPHONE VARCHAR2(15), 
CUSTOMEREMAIL VARCHAR2(50), 
CUSTOMERTYPE VARCHAR2(15)
)
```

TABLE MEMBER

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBER
(MEMBERID VARCHAR2(100), 
USERNAME VARCHAR2(25), 
PASSWORD VARCHAR2(10), 
CUSTOMERID VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT FK_Member Foreign Key (CustomerId)
REFERENCES Customer(CustomerId)
);
```

This is my trigger

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER insertMember
after insert ON CUSTOMER
for each row
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
If (select customertype from customer) = 'member'
begin
  INSERT INTO MEMBER (customerid ) values
  (:new.customerid);

END insertMember;
/
```

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `SET NOCOUNT ON`?

Comment: @a_horse_with _no_name I google it.maybe it is not for oracle.